# vagrant puppet, composer unable to install laravel

Tags: laravel, vagrant, composer-php, puppet, vagrant-provision

I just recently knew about puppet and I'm trying to install laravel while vagrant is provisioning so that everything is already set (can be able to run laravel) when I logged in/ssh to vagrant. But I got stuck, it returned ***successfully executed*** but after I do vagrant ssh, ***laravel command is not available.***

php5, php5-cli, etc. composer and other dependencies is already installed before this part of code.

```
class laravel {

    Exec {
        path => "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin",
    }

    exec { "install-laravel" :
        command     => "/usr/local/bin/composer global require 'laravel/installer'",
        require     => [Package["php5-cli", "php5-dev"], Exec["install-composer", "set-composer-as-global"]],
        cwd         => "/home/vagrant/",
        environment => ["COMPOSER_HOME=/home/vagrant"],
        user        => root, 
        group       => root,
    }

    exec { "add-laravel-command" :
        command     => "mkdir /usr/local/bin/laravel",
        environment => ["LARAVEL_HOME=/home/vagrant"],
        onlyif      => "test -d /usr/local/bin/composer",
        require     => Exec["install-laravel"],
        user        => root, 
    }

    exec { "set-laravel-as-globall" :
        command     => "mv /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin /usr/local/bin/laravel",
        onlyif      => "test -d /.composer/vendor/bin",
        require     => Exec["add-laravel-command"],
        user        => root, 
    }
}
```

Output

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Laravel/Exec[install-laravel]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Debug: /Stage[main]/Laravel/Exec[install-laravel]: The container Class[Laravel] will propagate my refresh event
==> default: Debug: Exec[add-laravel-command](provider=posix): Executing check 'test -d /usr/local/bin/composer'
==> default: Debug: Executing 'test -d /usr/local/bin/composer'
==> default: Debug: Exec[set-laravel-as-globall](provider=posix): Executing check 'test -d /.composer/vendor/bin'
==> default: Debug: Executing 'test -d /.composer/vendor/bin'
==> default: Debug: Class[Laravel]: The container Stage[main] will propagate my refresh event
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the output from the puppet provisioning?

Comment: hi @MattSchuchard I've added output above. Thanks

Comment: That output is from a re-provision and not the initial provisioning, but it does still seem to point at puppet not being the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file under `puppet/modules/laravel/files` and name it `composer.json` with the following content

```
{                                            
    "require": {                             
        "laravel/installer": "^1.3"          
    }                                        
}
```

Laravel init.pp file

```
class laravel {

    Exec {
        path => "/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin",
        user => root,
        group => root,
    }

    file { "/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools" :
        ensure  => directory,
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
    }

    file { "/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools/composer.json" :
        source  => "puppet:///modules/laravel/composer.json",
        require => File["/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools"],
        owner   => root,
        group   => root,
    }

    exec { "install-laravel" :
        command     => "sudo composer require 'laravel/installer'",
        onlyif      => "test -f /usr/local/bin/composer",
        require     => [
            Package["nginx","php5-cli", "php5-dev", "php5-mysql"], 
            File["/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools", "/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools"],
        ],
        environment => ["COMPOSER_HOME=/home/vagrant"],
        cwd         => "/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools", 
        user        => root, 
        group       => root,
    }

    exec { "set-laravel-as-global" :
        command => "sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools/vendor/laravel/installer/laravel /usr/local/bin/laravel",
        require => [
            File["/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools", "/usr/local/bin/laravel-devtools/composer.json"],
            Exec["install-laravel"],
        ],
    }

}
```

Make sure `composer` is installed first during provision.